# Abnormal for loop in NSIS

Tags: for-loop, nsis

I've got NSIS code like this:

```
    ;Installer Sections

    var /GLOBAL f1m

    Function GetXML
     StrCpy $path "/A/B/C/"
     StrCpy $path "$path$R1"
     ${UpdateXml} "http://127.0.0.1/denwer/update.xml" $path $f1m
    FunctionEnd

    Function DownloadFiles
     metadl::download /RETRYTIME=2 /MAXTRIES=2 /MD5 $f1m http://127.0.0.1/some.exe some.exe
     Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
     StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
     MessageBox MB_OK "Download failed: $R0"
    FunctionEnd

    Section "Dummy Section" SecDummy
    ...
    ReadRegStr $curver HKCU "Software\SomeSoft" "ver"
    ...
    ${For} $R1 1 10
     Call GetXML
     Call DownloadFiles
    ${Next}
    ...
SectionEnd
```

When programm in for loop runs "DowloadFiles" function it's back not in the begining of for loop. It's just back to ReadRegStr command and always gets same value of $f1m variable and stuck on a loop.

What's the cause of this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DonwloadFiles` function, I see a dubious

```
StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
```

That should jump to the 2nd next statement if the strings are equal (`+1` is the next statement, `+2` let shortcircuit the next statement, and `+3` will shunt the next 2 statements).

But there is only **one** statement after the `StrCmp` : the `MessageBox`. It is probable that when the strings are equal the flow is jumping to an unexpected statement... Use `+2` to jump over the message box, or use a label to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping past a functions end is not supported/undefined. You should consider using labels or [LogicLib.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Include/LogicLib.nsh)...